# How to select a default value in a slicer in Power BI?

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

Happy New Year!
I am new in Power BI. I have a question regarding DAX. I have a slicer with region names and a clustered column chart showing total revenue divided by months. But I want the chart always arranged to the highest selling region by default. If I do not apply any slicer selection, it automatically shows about the highest selling region only. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question title and question ask is not clear. Please update your question and make it clear what you are stuck with. Provide a screen grab (with annotation if relevant) to help illustrate the need.